# from os import path import sys sys.path.append(path.abspath('../ProgA'))

Tags: python

I don't understand what the below code does.

```
from os import path
import sys
sys.path.append(path.abspath('../ProgA'))
```

Comment: Read [the docs for `sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from os import path
```

imports path from the os module
this is used in line 3

```
import sys
```

imports the sys module

```
sys.path.append(path.abspath('../ProgA'))
```

This line is kinda tricky so ill break it down

path.abspath() takes a relative path (from the file executing the code) and gives you the absolute path to that

for example if you are in the directory /home/user/adi/documents and you call path.abspath('../ProgA'), the .. means you go up a directory a then look for a directory called ProgA so the final path will be /home/user/adi/ProgA

sys.path is just the place where python looks for imports
this is by default in you site packages but you edit this variable

TLDR;
the code append the directory ../ProgA to your sys.path so that you can import modules from the directory

Comment: so basically this can be useful if scriptA is in a different project folder from scriptB and I have to import scriptB in scriptA and I can't simply do it with "import scriptB"?